# How to update a field on a Record Type in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to update a existing Record in CloudKit but I'm creating a new Record instead of changing the value! Here it is the code:

```
func pairing(phone: String, ctid: String) {
    ctUsers = [CKRecord]()
    print("THE PHONE IS: \(phone)\n")

    let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = Predicate(format: "phone == %@", phone)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Elder", predicate: predicate)

    publicData.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results: [CKRecord]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let users = results {
            self.ctUsers = users
            print("\nHow many users in cloud: \(self.ctUsers.count)\n")

            if self.ctUsers.count != 0 {

                let user = CKRecord(recordType: "Elder")
                user["careTakerId"] = ctid

                let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
                publicData.save(user, completionHandler: { (record: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) in
                    if error == nil {

                        DispatchQueue.main.asynchronously(execute: { () -> Void in
                            print("CARETAKER updated successfully\n")
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        print("\nHUEHUEHUEHUE\n")
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                print("\nELDER ISN'T IN CLOUD\n")
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quick explanation: First I'm getting the elder's phone number (every elder has a different phone) and check if this phone number is in cloud. If it is, then updates the *careTakerId* of THIS elder, specifically!

[image]
Here you can see that is creating this "No Name" record and the record above remains unchanged

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, and don't mind the syntax, I'm using xcode 8 beta 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only realized now where is the problem:

```
publicData.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results: [CKRecord]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }

    if let users = results {
        self.ctUsers = users
        print("\nHow many users in cloud: \(self.ctUsers.count)\n")

        if self.ctUsers.count != 0 {

            let user =  users.first //CKRecord(recordType: "Elder")
            user?["careTakerId"] = ctid

            let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
            publicData.save(user, completionHandler: { (record: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) in
                if error == nil {

                    DispatchQueue.main.asynchronously(execute: { () -> Void in
                        print("CARETAKER updated successfully\n")
                    })
                }
                else {
                    print("\nHUEHUEHUEHUE\n")
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            print("\nELDER ISN'T IN CLOUD\n")
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I was literally creating a new record! I only needed to access the *results* variable, that is a vector of CKRecord and then change and save the field!

Answer (score 9):

Do it simplest way, fetch the record, update, and save:

```
    let recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: "[record_name_here]")

    database.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { record, error in

        if let record = record, error == nil {

            //update your record here

            self.database.save(record) { _, error in
                completion?(error)
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , very useful.